# Groovy grep and strip text

Tags: groovy

```
def data = '''
text
text
messageCount: 50,
name: muzipuzi-management,
text
text
messageCount: 10,
name: izapziza-error,
text
text
messageCount: 0,
name: uzi2-error,
text
'''


def messages = (data.split( '\n').findAll {it.startsWith ( 'messageCount:')})
def name = (data.split( '\n').findAll {it.startsWith ( 'name:') && it.endsWith('-error,') })


Map map =  GroovyCollections.transpose([name, messages])
        .collect {le -> [(le[0]):le[1]]}.collectEntries { it }

println (map)
```

I need to build a key value data where all keys are the name ending with "-error"
and corresponding data is the numbers after "messages" (which appear one line before the name)

currently i can grep the data but i need to find a way to strip it so in the end id get
data = ["izapziza-error" : 10, "uzi2-error" : 0]

Comment: I suppose you mean *...is the numbers after "messageCount:"*?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's easier if you start by splitting the string into related lines to avoid having to zip afterwards.

This splits on the position before `messageCount`, then uses just the first two lines:

```
def map = data.split('(?=messageCount)')
              .collect{it.split(',')}
              .findAll{it[0].startsWith('messageCount')}
              .collect{it[0..1]}
              .collectEntries{[(it[1].replace('name:', '')): 
                                it[0].replaceAll('messageCount|,|:','')]}
```

Which, with your test data, produces

```
[
    muzipuzi-management: 50, 
    izapziza-error: 10, 
    uzi2-error: 0
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your pairs right next to each other, you can use a regexp to
extract all the data.  E.g.

```
def data = '''
text
text
messageCount: 50,
name: muzipuzi-management,
text
text
messageCount: 10,
name: izapziza-error,
text
text
messageCount: 0,
name: uzi2-error,
text
'''

def regexp = /(?m)messageCount: (\d+),\nname: (.*?)-error,/
println(
(data =~ regexp).collect{ _, cnt, name ->
    [name, cnt.toLong()]
}.collectEntries()
)
// → [izapziza:10, uzi2:0]
```

This uses `(?m)` to scan over lines, a group for the count and the name
without `-error`, collects all results and transforms it into a map.
(the `Matcher` seems to only have `collect` and not `collectEntries`,
there for the "indirection").